# python opencv не удается вывести изображение, не создается окно

Tags: python, opencv

Всем привет, не судите строго. Не могу понять, использую библиотеку opencv максимально простой код, отрабатывает без ошибок, но изображение не считывает, в чем может быть проблема ?

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("C:\\python_project\\1524.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
print(img)
```

Comment: Вы принтом открываете окно?

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой код сможет показать изображение:

```
import cv2
retval = cv2.imread('45dd60cb7ef14bd4bfeb4c9061919e67.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
size_img = retval.shape
print(size_img)

cv2.imshow("Img", retval)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```